# Efficient way to drop a row from Dataframe A if an element equals an element in Dataframe B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in Dataframe B that contains elements I wish to drop from Dataframe A, should A contain them. I wish to drop the entire row from A.

I'm not new to programming but I am learning the extensive pandas library. From what I've seen, this can't be in any way efficient or proper.

```
for i in range(0,106):
    for j in range(0,171):
        if dfB.iloc[i,2] == dfA.iloc[j,0]:
            dfA.drop(j, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] ? Seems straightfoward with `pd.isin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
dfA = dfA.loc[~dfA["ColumnNameInA"].isin(dfB["ColumnNameInB"])]
```

You would need to substitute the appropriate column names.

In this case, `dfA["ColumnNameInA"].isin(dfB["ColumnNameInB"])` creates a series that is `True` whenever the value in `dfA`'s column is in `dfB`'s column. We pass that to `.loc`, and reassign to `dfA`.

Comment: Hmmm in your instance, when we reassign dfA, the series will be True when the condition of the two being equal is met. So won't this new dataframe be comprised only of the duplicate entries? Rather than keeping everything but the duplicate entries?

Comment: @BenW Sorry. Just negate it, and you'll have what you're looking for. I've edited the line.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
df = df[df['A'] == df2['B']]
```

Assumption: df and df2 are the same lengths, and you are comparing row x from df to row x from df2.

Example Dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1,4,3]})
```

Output:

```
df


    A
0   1
2   3
```